# call method between two objects SCALA

Tags: scala, object, apache-spark, error-handling, large-data

I have the following two methods, how can I call the method defined in DocsObj into DistanceObj?

The first object is:

```
object DocsObj{
     def Docs(s: List[String], b:Int): List[String] = { ... }
}
```

The second one is:

```
object Distance{
    def tanimoto(l1: List[String], l2: List[String]): Float={
        var list1= List[String]()
        list1=DocsObj.Docs(l1,6).asInstanceOf[List].toSet
    }
}
```

the error is the following one:

```
<console>:29: error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
found   : [B >: String]scala.collection.immutable.Set[B]
required: List[String]
   list1=DocsObj.Docs(list1,6).asInstanceOf[List[String]].toSet
```

Comment: Why are you calling `.asInstanceOf[List]`? `Docs` already returns a `List[String]`.

Comment: You don't need `return` in Scala, it's a Java-ism. It exists in Scala but you only use it in special situations; it doesn't appear in normal Scala code. Unless you're really sure you need it, just leave it out.

Comment: You define `list1` as `List[String]` but you attempt to assign a `Set`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the value you are attempting to assign to `list1` is a `Set`, but the `list1` var is of type `List`.

The compiler error explains this as best it can, but perhaps the error message is a bit obscure because the right hand side of the assignment could take many types ("polymorphic expression"), so the "found" line in the error message is a range of types, rather than a single type.

Try either changing `list1` to be of type `Set[String]` or changing the `toSet` call to a `toList` call.